# How to display a particular area?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm developing a plugin in Python for QGIS.

I would like the user to select a particular area in a list (let's say a country list) and zoom in the map on the corresponding area.

Actually I'm doing it 'ugly':I create a layer (from a WKT), zoom to this particular layer, and delete this layer...

Is there a way to do it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rect = geometry.boundingBox()
iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(rect)
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Comment: The problem with this, is that some other plugins does the same at launch time.